# Laravel Redirect to an specific URL

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I am using laravel 5.8 and i want a middleware or some technique that can stops unprivileged user to visit any other URL except an specific URL.

When unprivileged user visit a url, he/she should immediately be redirected to a specific allowed page.

```php
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware(['verified',...]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you routes file you should run all routes where only authenticated user should have access through the `auth` middlware.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    // more routes
});
```

To specify where the user should be redirected to you can open the middleware at [`app/Http/Middlware/Authentication.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php#L7) and check the method

```php
protected function redirectTo($request)
```